# Adding an Existing Folder to Eclipse project (STS)

Tags: eclipse

I have an error in the Problems window of Eclipse that says....

`The project was not built due to "Error deleting resource 'ProjectName/target/classes/log4j.xml' from the workspace tree." .Fix the problem, then try refreshing this project and building it since it may be inconsistent.`

[image]

The problem I'm having is that the `classes/log4j.xml` exist on the file system, but I can't import it. When I go to **File > Import > General > File System** and choose the **classes/log4j.xml** as the source I get a message saying that **"Source is in the heirarchy of the destination"** and it doesn't allow me to finish the wizard.

[image: Can't import screenshot]

What do I need to do to get the project to recognize

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Provide the destination folder, see `Into folder` text field under `From directory`

Since it's empty, Eclipse thinks that you want to add log4j.xml to the same place

Comment: It's saying that "Source is in the hierarchy of the destination". Basically the IDE is contradicting itself because the folder isn't showing up in the IDE's project, but it won't let me import from the file system because it says that it already exists.